# How do you dynamically display a button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, dynamic

Below I have code where I am trying to dynamically create a button using Javascript (I don't want to just create a button with HTML) When I locally run the web page no button appears.

The buttonActionFunction is a separate function I have (that is fully working) where an image appears when the button is clicked.

Also how do I add to that code so that once the button is clicked that the button deactivates so they can't click it again?

```
<script>
    function buttonFunction() {
        var button= document.createElement("button");
        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me"));
        button.onclick=buttonActionFunction();
        document.getElementById("divId").appendChild(button);
    }
    buttonFunction();
    </script>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or snippet ?

Comment: @PunitGajjar I don't understand what you mean, I'm new to Javascript!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net provide working example and share here

Comment: thanks for sharing the link  @lordkain

Comment: can you share you html code

Comment: @CHiRAG I am barely using any HTML, I'm trying to use as much JS as possible. the only html I have are my tags like head and script.

Comment: see answer with working fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function createButton(context, func) {
     var button = document.createElement("input");
     button.type = "button";
     button.value = "Click Me";
     button.onclick = func;
     context.appendChild(button);
 }
 function functienaam()
 {
     createButton(document.body, functienaam);
 }
 createButton(document.body, functienaam);
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fv42orad/1/

Comment: That is great thanks, I got it working! I just made some slight changes. Where you had functienaam I added my function that gave the action for the button and then at the botton when you have createButton I just removed the stuff in brackets and now it works perfectly. Thank so much for your help you absolute legend

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div id="divId"></div>` to your html

As for disabling the button on click

```
   function buttonActionFunction(e) {
        e.target.disabled = true
    }
```

and `button.onclick=buttonActionFunction;` not 
`button.onclick=buttonActionFunction();`

Comment: to add to it, `button.onclick=buttonActionFunction();` should rather be `button.onclick=buttonActionFunction;`

Comment: Then make sure that `<div>` is declared in html doc before the js code :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@lordKain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719755/lordkain) answer I've updated the code to disable the previous button when it is clicked, as shown bellow:

```
function createButton(context){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Click Me";
    button.onclick = function() {functienaam(button)};
    context.appendChild(button);
}
 function functienaam(button)
 {
 createButton(document.body);
 button.disabled = true;
 }
createButton(document.body);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5unLc5xr/